# She is more than a friend. [parse]

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, comparisons

> *She is more than a friend*.

As I understand, "*more than a friend*" is a constituent. The dependent "*than a friend*" is a prepositional phrase. The head "*more*" is a pronoun. Am I right? Thanks!